# What is the use of cmake namespaces if you can link without them?

Tags: cmake

I've been following the docs at https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-packages.7.html#creating-packages to create an installable package.

After adding the namespace to my project at the same place as suggested at that link, I was succesfully able to link using that namespace.

However, simply taking the namespace away with just the library name, I was still able to link against my library.

What is the use of the namespace in cmake if it isn't required? Or have I set up something incorrectly? I really don't want consumers of my library to just be able to type "graphics" - they should have to type the full "myLib::graphics" out.

Comment: "Or have I set up something incorrectly?" - It is difficult to answer that without viewing your setup (that is, the code and the way you run it).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cmake usefulness of aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46567646/cmake-usefulness-of-aliases)

Answer (score 0):

The use is so that it is *possible* to use the namespace version. This is useful when a library is used via `add_subdirectory`/`FetchContent`, so the usage can be written the same way if it were to be switched to use `find_package` (which will import targets with the namespace prefix). If you're worried about target name clashes, just prefix your target names like `myLib_graphics`, and then use the [`EXPORT_NAME`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/EXPORT_NAME.html) target property to remove the prefix for the export.