How to Setup CMake project to use local Libraries?
Imagine the following setup:
You have a number of personal libraries and apps: libA, libB, libC, appA, appB which have dependency trees like:
appA -> {libA}
libC -> {libA}
appB -> {libB, libC}

Where appA depends on libA, and appB also depends on libA transitively from libC.
All libs are under active development, so it would be useful for everything to share the latest versions.
One approach is to store all projects at the same level, and use add_subdirectory():
.
├── appA
├── appB
├── libA
├── libB
└── libC

appA CMakeLists.txt e.g.:
add_executable(appA main.cpp)
add_subdirectory(../libA libA)
target_link_library(appA PRIVATE libA)

libC CMakeLists.txt e.g.:
add_library(libC ${libc_SRC})
add_subdirectory(../libA libA)
target_link_library(libC PUBLIC libA)

appB CMakeLists.txt e.g.:
add_executable(appB main.cpp)
add_subdirectory(../libB libB)
add_subdirectory(../libC libC)
target_link_library(appA PRIVATE libB libC)

This approach works well since it adds the source directly to the build so you can edit it directly from anywhere and everyone else can see the edits (unlike if consuming packages, since that is based on the latest install).
However, this approach obviously doesn't work if you ever want to consume the libs outside of this environment (clone libA and place it at the same level at libC in order to use libC in something else? yuck)
Is there some way to setup find_package() so it works exactly like add_subdirectory() if a specific environment variable is set? That way all uses of add_subdirectory() can be replaced? I'd like to commit the changes so it works as expected if consuming via an installation, but then I can configure my environment so it works in the way described above for development

Am I correct to say, that you want to have the libraries in the form of the source code, but installed system-wide, so all CMake projects in the system can use it?

Have you explored Alias Targets? https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#alias-targets

See the answer by Craig Scott here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46567646/cmake-usefulness-of-aliases

Based on what I'm read, I think I can answer my own question:
Update each library with the following:
add_library(libA::libA ALIAS libA)
libA::libA is added as an alias, even when the library is included via a call to add_subdirectory(../libA libA)
Now the applications that includes libA via add_subdirectory() can link against libA::libA, since that just points to libA
target_link_libraries(appA PRIVATE libA::libA)

However, since libC depends on libA, in the context of building appA, libC knows about libA which is good, however, if libC is added to another project, for it to builid it now relies on that project adding libA for target_link_libraries(libC INTERFACE libA::libA) to succeed, which isn't good.
So we still need to call find_package(libA REQUIRED) in libC to make that dependency non-transparent, but this fails if we don't want to consume libA as an external package, and hence haven't installed it.
So the solution is to check if libA::libA is available, and if not, then try to use find_package(libA REQUIRED)
e.g.
if (NOT TARGET libA::libA)
    find_package(libA CONFIG REQUIRED)
endif()

Now if libA has been made available to libC via add_subdirectory(../libA libA) earlier, then libC can find it since its just another project in the build tree, and it defined the symbol libA::libA. However, if libC is being consumed in another way, then libA::libA won't be defined, and so it tries to find it where it was installed. If that succeeds, it defines libA::libA if following the usual convention.
So in either case, libC can find what it needs.
